# Creating Floating Action Button with Animated subaction menus

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

I am creating an app in which I am creating new floating action button with few sub actions associated with the FAB.

I tried [This library](https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu).
It is working fine but it is not exactly what I want.

I want to add it in the tabs with each tab having different FAB with sub action menu. 
The problem with above library is FAB is not being removed after changing the tab.It is still showing in other tabs also even if I am adding it in one tab only(Every tab is a fragment).

And I also I want to use similar FAB used by Evernote with similar kind of animation.
Is anybody aware of any third party library or is there any API available in new Android SDK.

Thank you in advance for the Help!...

Comment: see if this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25349317/how-do-i-create-an-android-material-design-ui-widget/25349532#25349532

Comment: See this library https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the FAB in the XML layout of only the fragment and not the parent activity. That should ensure that it appears only the fragment(tab) and not everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of have the similar issue with that FAB library.

For your first question, you can try this, 
YourFABObject.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) when you switch to another tab, it works for me.

For your second question, if you mean the vertical extended FAB, I am using this one: https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button