# How do I make floating button clickable

Tags: java, android, user-interface, button, floating

Hi I was implementing a floating button with this post:
[How do I create an Android material design UI widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25349317/how-do-i-create-an-android-material-design-ui-widget/25349532#25349532)

and it works ! 
But I don`t know how to make this button clickable please help  ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook up a onClickListener to the FloatingActionButton view. By the way, the answer you quoted here was derived from [this blog post](http://prolificinteractive.com/blog/2014/07/24/android-floating-action-button-aka-fab/) by John Hogan and here is the sample code hosted on [Github](https://gist.github.com/Jogan/9def6110edf3247825c9) in case you would like to see the entire code sample.

```
FloatingActionButton mFab = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
            .withColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent_color))
            .withDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fab_icon))
            .withSize(72)
            .withMargins(0, 0, 16, 16)
            .create();
mFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // DO SOMETHING HERE
            }
        });
```